# Can OpenVPN create multiple tunnels?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, tunnel

I have a single Linux machine with 10 network interfaces, none of which support port forwarding. I am trying to find a solution where I can expose all 10 interfaces publicly, and I considered using OpenVPN or [FRP](https://github.com/fatedier/frp).

I did some research and frp doesn't support multiple tunnels, so for every tunnel I have to create another instance, resulting in 10 instances.

Can OpenVPN support creating multiple tunnels on multiple interfaces using on instance?

Comment: What’s wrong with having 10 instances?

Comment: see if it's helpful to you:https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=9277

Comment: I don't think it can, but couldn't you bridge all interfaces onto the OpenVPN adapter in Windows?  See `dev-node node` [here](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/).